# Using the .Caller.Column code to identify Column value and use it in seperate range lookup

Tags: function, excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying design a function that takes the Application.Caller.Column value and uses it to look up a range on a different sheet.

The function is being designed to take a value from a drop down box. That value will determine the row of the array and I used a Case statement to do that. The problem I am have in that I want the function to return Column B values from the other sheet if the Function is in Column B, so on and so forth.

I keep getting #Value return when I am using it and the smart tag is telling me "A value in the formula is of the wrong data type". Any help is Much appreciated!

Code

```
 Function NetPay(Scenario As Range)


 Dim CC As String
 CC = Application.Caller.Column
 Select Case Scenario

    Case 1: NetPay = Sheets("Scenarios").Cells(4, CC)
    Case 2: NetPay = Sheets("Scenarios").Cells(7, CC)
    Case 3: NetPay = Sheets("Scenarios").Cells(10, CC)
    Case 4: NetPay = Sheets("Scenarios").Cells(13, CC)
    Case 5: NetPay = Sheets("Scenarios").Cells(16, CC)
    Case 6: NetPay = Sheets("Scenarios").Cells(19, CC)
    Case 7: NetPay = Sheets("Scenarios").Cells(22, CC)


End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `CC` defined as a `String`.

Change the definition to a `Long`.

Also, your `Select Case` is taking a range, when you should be looking at the `.value`